# Python multiprocessing -> can not spawn Process within thread

Tags: python-3.6, windows-7-x64

I Create a thread inside the __main__ function by creating an object that inherits from threading.Thread. Inside its run method i open multiprocessing.Process with a target function that is in global namespace of the module but i get the error:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading

def executeTests(ScriptName, Params, MsgQueue, ResultQueue):
...

class TestRunner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, tests):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        ...
    def run(self):
        MsgQueue = Queue()
        ResultQueue = Queue()
        TestProcess = Process(target=executeTests, args=(ScriptName, Params, MsgQueue, ResultQueue))
        TestProcess.start()
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestRunner(...).start()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in sp
awn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _m
ain
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'executeTests' on <module '__main__' (built-
in)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
A join() was missing in **main**.